# AlphaImageLoader not honoring protocol relative paths

Tags: css

The following css is present in server1 and I want it to load images from server2. Only in IE(both 7&8) AlphaImageLoader doesn't load the image from server2. Instead a I see a request as follows and that results in a 404.

/path/to/webroot/in/server1/src='/server2.com/images/bg/main.jpg'

The css being used

```
#wrapper {
  margin-top: 5px;
  clear: both;
  background: url('//server2.com/images/bg/main.jpg') no-repeat scroll 0 0 #f0f3f5;
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='//server2.com/images/bg/main.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='//server2.com/images/bg/main.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
  zoom: 1;
}
```

I'm using an absolute path, but the browser assumes a relative path(relative to the document). Why?
I've tried using http in the image path, still find the same problem. How do I make AlphaImageLoader load from an absolute path.

Comment: In which versions of IE does this happen?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like the problem was including both filter and -ms-filter.
I've started using filter for the filter tag for IE7 and -ms-filter for IE8.
That fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

You are not wrapping the first `filter` value in quotes. The result you show looks more like a parsing problem than IE not being able to deal with protocol relative URLs inside `filter` statements.

Comment: I've tried adding and removing quotes. Could you write the filter block alone. I'll clearly understand what you have in mind.

Comment: @rampr I checked MSDN and they are using quote-less examples so that shouldn't be it. Maybe remove the double quotes from the `filter` statements? Does this happen for protocol relative URLs only, what happens if you use a truly relative one?

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that you don't need a background when you are using alphaloader.
Check this link:

[filter (CSS property)](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/filter)

Comment: Why not? The example in the link uses images.